# angular.jsのソートがうまくいかない

Tags: angularjs

angular.jsをつかって値の並び替え（降順・昇順）ソートできるように設定していて、
つまづきました。

問題が起こっているページは以下になります。
http://testdayo.chottu.net/

テーブルの１番目の列の「並び替え」をクリックすると
その項目で昇順・降順でソートされるのですが、

一番高い桁の数値だけで並び替えされてしまいます。

（5,400、4,950、980、980、500）とソートされたいのに
（980、980、500、5,400、4,950）となってしまいます。

整数値ではなく文字として認識しまっているのかと思います。

何が原因で、どのように設定すれば問題が解消されますでしょうか？
確認する箇所や解決方法のアドバイスをお願いします。

Comment: @oTak さん
「ng-clickの| numberを削除」し、
「JSONデータ取得後、数値型に変換」でしっかりとソートされました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

JSONデータ取得後、数値型に変換します。

```
  for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
    jsondata[i].result_dha_price1 = parseFloat(jsondata[i].result_dha_price1);
    jsondata[i].result_dha_price2 = parseFloat(jsondata[i].result_dha_price2);
    jsondata[i].result_dha_amount1 = parseFloat(jsondata[i].result_dha_amount1);
    jsondata[i].result_dha_amount2 = parseFloat(jsondata[i].result_dha_amount2);
  }
```

並び替えのng-clickの" | number"を削除します。

```
<th>料金A&nbsp;<a href="" ng-click="sort_data = '+result_dha_price1'; reverse=!reverse">並び替え</a></th>
<th>料金B&nbsp;<a href="" ng-click="sort_data ='+result_dha_price2'; reverse=!reverse">並び替え</a></th>
```